# In Azure DevOps release pipeline how to promote the latest version to a stage to which no releases were promoted for some time?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We use on-prem Azure DevOps Server 2019.

Observe the following release pipeline:
[image]

Notice the last stage - prod. No code was released to it for some time, but now I do want to release the latest there. But, right now I am forced to release and immediately cancel all the versions in the middle, because this is seemingly the only way to release the latest.

Is this the only way?

Comment: Go to the latest release, hover the mouse on the prod stage and click **Deploy**. Will this releases the latest to prod?

Comment: We redeployed only today. Let us accumulate a few omitted releases and then we will check.

Comment: Yes, it works. Can you arrange it as an answer? It is a mystery to me why it is not available immediately.

Comment: Great it worked. I posted the steps in below answer.

Comment: I was wrong and it does not work. I do not know what confused me previously, but it definitely does not work when there is pre-deployment approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this has been answered but i thought it might be worthwhile to point out that you can actually always ensure that you only promote the latest release by ensuring that the  **Deploy latest and cancel others** located on the **deployment queue settings** section of your pipeline is checked/selected on your prod release stage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rblr4.png

Comment: Could you make the image link actually available? You can paste an image directly

Comment: I have added the link as requested.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rblr4.png

Pre-Deployment Conditions > Deployment queue settings> subsequent releases

Comment: I do not know why, but I cannot find the documentation on this setting. How do I navigate to it? Can you point to the MSFT documentation. For some reason, it does not come up in searches.

Comment: Found it. It is on the same sheet where one configures the pre-deployment approvals for a stage.

Comment: I guess so. It is there and it is working as advertised, but this is not the semantics we need. We do not want it automatically deploy the latest release. We want it to deploy specific release. However, since I was asking about the latest release, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed steps is listed as below:

Select the release pipeline from **Releases** under **Pipelines** of your Azure devops project.

[image]

Select the latest release from the Releases history. Hover the mouse on the prod stage and click **Deploy** to deploy the latest release to prod environment.

[image]

Comment: I had to demote it from being the answer. It does not work. If we have 5 previous releases and the stage is stuck on pre-deployment approval, then trying to deploy the way you suggest is going to move the latest stage into the Queued state, but will not deploy it. When we cancel the deployment of the older version by refusing to approve, another old release will become active and wait on the approval. We will have to cancel all the older releases until we get to the latest. In short - does not work.

Comment: Could you please, confirm that you also see the problem?

Comment: I saw the problem. The previous deployments needs to be rejected or cancelled. It seems the only way to do it currently.

Comment: That is a major nuisance.